# Convert string (Jun 6, 2019 9:29:29 AM) into datetime (Y-M-D H:M:S) with Python -

Tags: python, datetime

I've the following date: `Jun 6, 2019 9:29:29 AM` in string format with python and I want to convert this string into  `2019-06-06 09:29:29`. I've tried with strptime but I always get an error in the processing:

```py
from datetime import datetime
date_string = "Jun 6, 2019 9:29:29 AM"
date_object = datetime.strptime(date_string, "%m %d, %Y %H:%M:%S %p")
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You want to convert `Jun 6, 2019 9:29:29 AM` into `2019-06-06 09:29:29`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> date_string = "Jun 6, 2019 9:29:29 AM"
>>> date_object = datetime.strptime(date_string,"%b %d, %Y %H:%M:%S %p")
>>> print(date_object)
2019-06-06 09:29:29
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fecha="May 29, 2019 9:10:07 PM"
fecha = datetime.strptime(fecha,"%b %d, %Y %H:%M:%S %p")
fecha = str(fecha)
print fecha
```

2019-05-29 09:10:07

the result is incorrect :( , the transformation from PM isnt correct

regards